# Google app engine JAVA: how to embed html in mail being sent while using java mail api on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

this is the working code i'm using to send the mail but if am including html content to the string argument of the setText() method then its being displayed merely as string to the user, no HTML effect.

```
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session1);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com", "Team Application"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, "Dear "+name1+"."));
        msg.setSubject("Registration confirmation mail");
        msg.setText("Dear "+name1+",\nThanks for registering with us.");
        Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 10):

try using setContent instead of setText 
so for your code sample:

```
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session1);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com", "Team Application"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, "Dear "+name1+"."));
    msg.setSubject("Registration confirmation mail");
    msg.setContent("Dear <i>"+name1+"</i>,<br>Thanks for registering with us.", "text/html");
    Transport.send(msg);
```

Personally, for this purpose I use multipart message with text and html version. This is part of my own code:

```
        // Unformatted text version
        final MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textPart.setText("plain content");
        // HTML version
        final MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent("<b>html content</b>", "text/html");
        // Create the Multipart.  Add BodyParts to it.
        final Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
        mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        // Set Multipart as the message's content
        msg.setContent(mp);
```

Comment: @ANSHUL JAIN: ignore it - this is POJO holding text message. getText() and getHtml() returns strings (now its removed from source).

Answer (score 1):

Checking the MimeMessage [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html), you could you the [setText()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) overloaded signature where you can specify *charset* and *Mime subtype*:

```
msg.setText("Your html body", "utf-8", "html");
```

Comment: In my case Mozilla Thunderbird doesn't parse msg.setText("Your html body", "utf-8", "html") correctly. However link <a href=.../> contained in message body

Answer (score 1):

You should use MailService.Message and MailService from low-level API. Example:

```
Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setSender(_sender);
    msg.setTo(_recipient);
    msg.setSubject(_msgSubject);
    msg.setHtmlBody("<h1 style="height:1200px;">THIS IS RUSSIA!!!</h1>");
    MailService service = MailServiceFactory.getMailService();
    try {
        service.send(msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. We gotta show the Russians some respect.

Comment: Please, don't shame russians. You should escape double quotes to make this peace of code works